# Ploting degree distribution for a directed network

Tags: matlab, social-networking

I have a dataset for the edges and nodes I've crawled from a social networking site. How can I plot the degree distribution using the data I have in a spreadsheet? The edges are directed. I am a MATLAB beginner. Please help.

I have created the adjacency matrix `adj` as follows:

```
clear all; 
disp('Processing Edge-List File');
A = xlsread('edges.csv');
dim = max(max(A));
[E_Size, junk] = size(A); 
sprintf('The dataset has %d nodes and %d edges',dim, E_Size);
disp('Filling Adjanceny Matrix');
adj = sparse(A(:,1), A(:,2), ones(E_Size,1), dim, dim, E_Size);
if(adj==adj') disp('Symmetric Adjacency Matrix - Undirected Graph') ;
else disp('Assymmetric Adjacency Matrix - Directed Graph');
```

Then i tried `surf(adj)` . its giving me an empty graph . Is there a problem in the way I am creating the adjacency matrix?

Comment: What format is your data in? Can you post a small example?

Comment: these are nodes , which have numeric lables and they are in the format 1->2 then 1 is in column 1 and 2 in in the second column of the xls

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to plot something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_distribution):
[image]

Once you have determined the in and out degree of each node, you need to store it in a matrix *A* such that *A(i,j)* represents the number of nodes with in-degree *i* and out-degree *j*.

Then you can display this information with [`surf(A)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html). `surf` plots an interpolated 3D surface where the intensity of each element in the matrix is the *Z*-coordinate of the surface and the column and row indices are the *X,Y* values.

Comment: If you're having issues obtaining the in-degree & out-degree information from your data set, please post a small sample as @Junuxx has suggested in his comment

Comment: i have created the adjacency matrix adj as follows-
clear all;

disp('Processing Edge-List File')

A = xlsread('edges.csv');

dim = max(max(A));
[E_Size, junk] = size(A);

sprintf('The dataset has %d nodes and %d edges',dim, E_Size)

disp('Filling Adjanceny Matrix')

adj = sparse(A(:,1), A(:,2), ones(E_Size,1), dim, dim, E_Size);

if(adj==adj')
    disp('Symmetric Adjacency Matrix - Undirected Graph')
else
    disp('Assymmetric Adjacency Matrix - Directed Graph')
end

and then i tried surf(adj) . its giving me an empty graph . is there a problem in the way I  am creating the adjacency matrix?

Comment: Please add such information to the original post henceforth (I just did it for you).